# Multiple types of User with many mutual attributes

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

How to create two `User` types with many mutual attributes? As far as I know, the best practise for creating two types of `User` is to create 2 `UserProfiles`. I have types - `Firm` and `Person`. So I've decided to create two `UserProfiles`:

```
class FirmProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='firmprofile')
    prefered_times = ...
    favourite_food = ...

class PersonProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='personprofile')
    prefered_times = ...
    favourite_food = ...
```

Now, I'm looking for a way I don't have to write those attributes twice. Is it possible?

EDIT: I've created this but I'm not sure if it's the best option because each UserProfile would have both profiles - firm and person

```
class UserProfile(User):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile')

    TYPE_OF_USER_CHOICES = (('firm','Firm'),
                            'person','Person')

    type_of_user = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=TYPE_OF_USER_CHOICES)

class FirmProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='firmprofile')

class PersonProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='personprofile')
```

Comment: What about having only one model with a field for person or firm? or set all your attributes in the UserProfile. So it is more easy to do your tests then. I dont think you need to have FirmProfile and PersonProfile if you have a UserProfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

Simplest would be creating [`abstract`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) model

```
class BaseProfile(models.Model):
    prefered_times = ...
    favourite_food = ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class FirmProfile(BaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='firmprofile')
    ... # all custom fields can be defined here

class PersonProfile(BaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='personprofile')
    ...
```

**Answering comment**
You can check type of user like this

```
def get_user_type(user):
    if getattr(user, 'firmprofile', None):
        return 'firm'
    elif getattr(user, 'personprofile', None):
        return 'person'
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: This seem quite good but there may be one problem. What If I work with user in some view for example, and I want to access their UserProfile? How can I know whether it's a firm or person? if 'user.type' = 'person' will not working...